# What is Estimated New Space?

Tags: space-usage

On the Storage Space Allocation page, what does Estimated New Space mean?

I understand Space Used and Space Remaining.

Answer (score 1):

It specifically deals with the growth rate of your data and the space you expect it to use.

[This link explains the overall purpose of storage space and growth](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298801.aspx)